# similar to ampersand for accessing item in an array in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working with a class that is a subclass of JsonApiClient::Resource and can access like this (not ampersand / try sytax):

```
 user&.professional_awards
```

which is like this with professional_awards being an array of Hash with Indifferent Access:

```
 {id: 23
  name: 'something',
  professional_awards:[
      {name: 'Best Smile'}, {name: 'Funniest'}
   ]
 }
```

My question is how I access the internal professional awards in a safe way? Is there a way I could use ampersand like syntax? Or do I have to manually check? Would like to do (and options in Rails hence tagged as):

```
 user&.professional_awards.first&['name'] # Best Smile
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [Hash#dig](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Hash.html#method-i-dig):

```
hash = {
  id: 23,
  name: 'something',
  professional_awards: [ { name: 'Best Smile' }, { name: 'Funniest' } ]
}

hash.dig(:id) # 23 
hash.dig(:professional_awards) # [{:name=>"Best Smile"}, {:name=>"Funniest"}]
hash.dig(:professional_awards, 1) # {:name=>"Funniest"}
```